# How to unset page numbering on beamer

Tags: beamer, page-numbering

I'm adding an annex after my last frame. How do I unable the page numbering, please?

Is it possible to show, instead of `30/30` this `--/--` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place an `\appendix` command just after the first frame of the annex; load the [`appendixnumberbeamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/appendixnumberbeamer) package so the pages in the annex are not taken into account for the total number of frames and `\let` the commands `\insertframenumber` and `\inserttotalframenumber` to be an en-dash in the appendix:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\endash{--}
\apptocmd{\appendix}
  {\let\insertframenumber\endash\let\inserttotalframenumber\endash}{}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\appendix
\begin{frame}
test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]